# jQuery loop to find data attribute and number them each a different number

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Hey all I am trying to find all data attributes and replace the name with a number count.

The example HTML is this:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation" data-name="0">
  <a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AScript</a>
</li>

<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation" data-name="0">
  <a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Something</a>
</li>

etc etc...
```

There are about 20 or so with that same **data-name** attribute. I am wanting to loop through the page, finding that attribute, and then replacing that number and adding the correct number to it.

As an example:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation" data-name="0">
  <a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AScript</a>
</li>

<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation" data-name="1">
  <a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Something</a>
</li>

<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation" data-name="2">
  <a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Hey there</a>
</li>

etc etc...
```

Notice how **data-name** is 0, 1, 2, etc etc.

That is what i am looking to do. Is that possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through any element with a certain property and then change that element, like in the example below:

```
$('[data-name]').each(function (e) {
    // Set the data-name to the item number
    $(this).attr('data-name', e);

    // Print the new `data-name` to the console
    console.log($(this).attr('data-name'));
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2tpJ/5/

Note: Take a look at this post to decide on using `attr` or `data`:
[jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: I don't think that would work. All the data-name's start out with "0". i am needing to change that to a unique number for each one it finds.

Comment: Ahh in that case you can replace the `$(this).attr('data-name', $(this).attr('data-name') + 'N');` line with `$(this).attr('data-name', e);`. Edited my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$("[data-name=0]").each(function(i) {
    $(this).data("name", i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First select all li tags who have an attribute called data-name, and with a loop, change it's value.

```
$('li[data-name]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-name',  i);
});
```

Edited: thought you only want to add a number to the end of the attribute.